# How to get initial list from which dict was built?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there are any way to determine `initial_list` i've build `my_dict` from, **only by using** that dictionary itself:

```
initial_list = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3'),
                (1,2), ('a','z'), ('aa','z')]
my_dict = dict(initial_list)
```

As I have found out one of the option to get initial list(but order of items in it is differs from original list) is by using [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) or [dict.items](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=items#dict.items):

```
initial_list_from = zip(my_dict.keys(),my_dict.values())
print initial_list_from == initial_list #False

initial_list_from = my_dict.items()
print initial_list_from == initial_list #False
```

The problem with such approach is that `my_dict == initial_list` evaluates to `false`, they aren't same...

Comment: Related [Python dictionary, keep keys/values in same order as declared](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1867861)

Comment: @BhargavRao definetely take  a look, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, because dict class **doesn't store order of keys** it was created from.

The only way to do that is by using [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict) which is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

initial_list = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2'), ('key3', 'value3'),
                    (1,2), ('a','z'), ('aa','z')]
my_dict = OrderedDict(initial_list)

initial_list_from = my_dict.items()
print initial_list_from == initial_list # True
```

Comment: try `my_dict.items()` instead of `zip(my_dict.keys(),my_dict.values())`!